# How to handle JSON to QueryDict to JSON

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

So I'm sending a JSON that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "Datum": "textholder1",
    "Bedrag": "",
    "Rekening": "",
    "Tegenrekening": "",
    "Naam": "",
    "Omschrijving": ""
  },
  {
    "Datum": "textholder2",
    "Bedrag": "",
    "Rekening": "",
    "Tegenrekening": "",
    "Naam": "",
    "Omschrijving": ""
  }
]
```

To the server via POST and when I retrieve it, it looks like this:

```
{
    "json[1][Omschrijving]": [""],
    "json[1][Rekening]": [""],
    "json[0][Datum]": ["textholder1"],
    "json[1][Tegenrekening]": [""],
    "json[0][Rekening]": [""],
    "json[0][Bedrag]": [""],
    "json[0][Naam]": [""],
    "json[1][Naam]": [""],
    "json[0][Tegenrekening]": [""],
    "json[1][Bedrag]": [""],
    "json[0][Omschrijving]": [""],
    "json[1][Datum]": ["textholder2"]
}
```

So as you can see it transforms the inner objects to `json[index]` instead of keeping its format. Is this normal behaviour or am I doing something wrong here? This is how I'm retrieving the data:

```
inputData = request.POST
userDataList = dict(inputData.lists())
print userDataList # prints the funny formatted JSON
print type(userDataList) # dict
print type(inputData) # django.http.request.QueryDict
```

How im seeding to the server:

```
 frm = $("#textCSVForm");
frm.submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    $.ajax({
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            dataType: '',
            data: {
                json: json.data
            },
            beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
                }
            }
        })
        .done(function(response) {
        })
        .fail(function() {})
        .always(function() {
          console.log(json.data); // logs the first formatted JSON
        });
});
```

Comment: Why are you turning it to a list?

Comment: @Rishav are you referring to the ```.lists()``` ? There is no difference in output with or without it according to my test results. But i have no particular reason why im using ```.lists()``` i tried it because its an array with objects.

Comment: How are you sending the data to the server?

Comment: @Rishav I've updated is this enough or do you need more info ? Im using Django form system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you send and receive JSON through Django.

Ajax call like this:

```
var t = {
     'foo': 1,
     'bar': 2,
};

$.ajax({
            url: 'localhost',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'data': JSON.stringify(t),
            },
        });
```

And Django view like this:

```
def test(request):
    import json
    print(json.loads(request.POST['data']))
    return HttpResponse('ok')
```

Comment: hmm i remember i tried something like this, and then i got the same error as im getting now ```MultiValueDictKeyError: "'json'"``` so i just dropped this method (i tried almost every solution i could find online but none worked) and tried the way as i did above. But  if i manage to fix this multiValue error i should get the JSON formatted correctly ?

Comment: @Kevin i just tested an alternative method and it works now

Comment: OMG this is actually smart :D thanks for your solution!